# Spring Cloud Discovery First Configuration Server Decryption Failed

Tags: spring-boot, encryption, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am trying discovery first implementation with Spring Cloud. I am getting failure for password decryption. I have .jks in the classpath. The same works when I go for Config First approach.

Following is the bootstrap.properties file for Config first approach.

```
eureka.instance.hostname=claims-dev
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
spring.cloud.config.name=claim
spring.config.import=configserver:http://localhost:8888
spring.profiles.active=dev
spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true
```

Following is the bootstrap for Discovery First approach.

```
eureka.instance.hostname=claims-dev
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/

spring.cloud.config.discovery.service-id=configserver
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.name=claim
spring.profiles.active=dev
spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true
```

For Discovery First I am getting below exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No decryption for FailsafeTextEncryptor. Did you configure the keystore correctly?
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.TextEncryptorUtils$FailsafeTextEncryptor.decrypt(TextEncryptorUtils.java:188) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.AbstractEnvironmentDecrypt.decrypt(AbstractEnvironmentDecrypt.java:144) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
... 16 common frames omitted
```

What I am missing here?

UPDATE: Following are the config server properties

```
encrypt.keyStore.location=classpath:/store name
encrypt.keyStore.password=store password
encrypt.keyStore.alias=alias
encrypt.key-store.type=jks
spring.cloud.config.server.encrypt.enabled=false
```

It works if I opt for server side password decryption.

Comment: Where do your keep you encryption key?

Comment: @spencergibb have added .jks store in class path of config server and client. I am decrypting password on the client side. I have updated the config server properties in the description.

Comment: If you go discovery first, then those properties aren't at the client and you get those errors. I'm not sure decryption with keys stored on config server is possible with discovery first.

Comment: Yes..so if I copy the key store properties in the bootstrap.properties of client then it works. Ideally I wanted this to get from git via config. But seems like if client has this details right from the beginning then decryption on client side works.

Comment: You have a chicken and egg problem. Keys can't be on config server for discovery first.

Comment: Yes for now I am settling up with keys on client side. Thank you @spencergibb for your support.